# Skipping a row because of a delimiter mismatch in Visual Studio SSIS package

Tags: visual-studio, csv, import, ssis, delimiter

So I'm trying to import a series of CSVs using an SSIS package made in Visual Studio 2019.
These CSVs contain a field where a person has written a response, and occasionally someone will have written something like:

"","","","","this is my message, it has a **"quote"** from something else in it","","",""

Or something like

"","","","","this is my message, it has a **"mark** for some reason","","",""

I'm trying to get VS to ignore these rows during the running of the package, but because it's using quotes as text-qualifiers, it ends up reading the quotation marks from those fields and getting that delimiter error.
Is there any clever way around this, that doesn't involve reformatting the file?